# get data from between two stings in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following String

```
$str = "Loreum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet <code>Some HTML Code like <h1>Head</h1></code>. Loreum Ipsum <code>Some Code</code> Dolor Sit Amet."
```

What I need is to get the value from inside all the code tags and apply a PHP function of `str_replace()` to that data and join the string back.

```
str_replace('<', '&lt;', $sub_str);
```

I have tried using `explode()` but was unable to get all the `<code>` tags from the string.

Comment: What are some sample inputs and their desired outputs for your query? Also, please provide an explanation for your outputs if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to pull out the string within `<code></code>` tags, replace text and join anything back. It can all be done using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
<?php
$str = "Loreum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet <code>Some HTML Code like <h1>Head</h1></code>. Loreum Ipsum <code>Some Code</code> Dolor Sit Amet.";
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '|(?s)(?<=<code>).*?(?=</code>)|',
    function ($matches) {
        return str_replace('<', '&lt;', $matches[0]);
        // to replace '>' also:
        //return str_replace('>', '&gt;', str_replace('<', '&lt;',$matches[0]));
    },
    $str
);
echo $str;
```

Prints:

```
Loreum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet <code>Some HTML Code like &lt;h1>Head&lt;/h1></code>. Loreum Ipsum <code>Some Code</code> Dolor Sit Amet.
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rhZ0Ld/1/)

1. `(s)` Sets single-line mode so that `.` matches the newline character.
2. `(?<=<code>)` A lookbehind assertion stating that the preceding characters match `<code>`.
3. `.*?` A non-greedy match matching 0 or more characters until ...
4. `(?=</code>)` A lookahead assertion stating that the following characters match `<code>`.

[PHP Demo](https://ideone.com/hqW86G)